# Can javascript access the users Region and Language format preferences on the control panel?

Tags: c#, javascript

I am working on a project to grab the users region settings based on what they set in the Control panel. I was easily able to access that information via C# in the System.Globalization.RegionInfo class. Is there a javascript equivalent? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Globalization settings in C# is for the server and not for the user visiting a web page.

In JavaScript the only option is to look at userLanguage or language

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage  || navigator.browserLanguage;
```

On the server you can check the [Accept Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header. Still, this is the browser settings and not the system settings.

**Edit**: Added navigator.BrowserLanguage after @fred02138's comment.

Comment: In IE it is navigator.browserLanguage.

Comment: Okay I used your code block and it seems to be working but only for IE. I guess the other browsers use their preferences based on the browser setting. However, no matter what language I changed it to, Chrome never seemed to work.

Comment: Good catch! I just confirmed this, and I was a bit surprised. But then the best solution would be to rely on the Accept Language header. Good to know :)

Comment: Good stuff. I pulled up fiddler and it appears the Accept-Language in the header varies from browser to browser. For instance, the Accept-Language in the header of the packet for IE showed up as en-CA because I changed my region format to that in the Control Panel in my region settings. However, in Chrome, I have to set my preferences through the browser because the Accept-Language came back as "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-CA;q=0.6" which is what I set my settings to on the browser.